# Why does water accumulate on the hardwood floors in my 1930 home?

Tags: flooring, bedroom, old-house, condensation

My home was build 1930 and nothing has been updated. In my downstairs bedroom under anything that sits on the floor from my bed, night stands, dog crate, and other things the floors will puddle with water.

I have done some research and come to the conclusion that I have a condensation problem, but everything that I have read talks about concrete foundation and basements primarily. My house does not have a concrete foundation or at least one I can see. This house sits on brick pillars in the front and ground in the back as it was built on a downhill slope.

My laundry room that was an addon has a concrete foundation, but I have no issues in any other part of the house but my bedroom which sits at the front of the house so it's off the ground which means air flow. I have drilled a couple of holes through the wall to the outside to help promote some air flow but that didn't seem to affect anything.

I have gas heater and though maybe the heat mixed with the cold floor is causing build up so I turned the heat off and no progress. This house also has no insulation and was built with small wood slabs (wrong term for what's it called but I can't recall the name but small thin 1-2 inch wide, 1/2 thick, length varies wood boards) Looks like it was made like an old doll house with popsicle sticks.

I don't know much about this issue and am seeking help for answers as to what could be the problem so I can fix it. Does anyone by chance have any clue what it could be? Thank you any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Puddle" implies a thick layer of standing water. Is that what you have, or is it just dew or mist on the surface? Photos would be great.

Comment: Drilling those holes made it worse, not that a crawl space shouldn't be vented, but doing so lets the floor get cold enough to condense water above it. Insulate the bedroom floor with batts (the only problem area because it's not in contact with the ground, so it gets no ground heat and w/e heat there is gets blown away). - Turn the heat off, open all the windows, let it acclimate for several hours, and I'd bet it doesn't condense anymore (not a real suggestion).

Comment: I'm Sorry I have tried multiple different ways to upload a photo. It puddles like if I put on rain boots I could stomp around and play in the pools of water on my floor ( Not meaning that in a rude way at all just trying to drawl an image I guess).

Comment: Question is your floor flat or does a ball tend to roll on it?  Your main problem is using heat but no insulation in humid condition, warm wet air hitting cold surface.  Almost cheaper just to burn the money

Comment: It's definitely not completely any point of my how a ball will roll somewhere.

Comment: Click [edit], then above the text entry box, click the "sun & mountain" icon. You can paste in a link to your picture(s) from there. Or, even better, once you're [edit]ing your post, you can simply drag the pics into the text edit box from your PC and the site will automatically upload & embed the images for you. If you still can't get it, upload them someplace like imgur and paste the link into the comments & someone will embed them for you.

Comment: Is that gas heater room-sealed or not?  Most new ones where I live are, and shouldn't cause condensation except by evaporating water with their heat, but some old ones would allow you to (hypothetically of course) put your finger in the flame, and they emit water vapour into the room, along with CO2.  These require good ventilation to prevent CO from being produced

Comment: Also, what's your climate? Is the water problem seasonal, and if so when is it best/worst?

Answer (score 1):

Certain sealants for floors reduce permeability. If you have a sealant or its over oiled it could be inhibiting the woods ability to "breathe". That is to say absorb and dissipate moisture.

Have you added spray foam insulation under your house or added some kind of vapor barrier under your house?

If you have been updating and insulating in an old house you can change the way moisture and air flow. One of the quickest fixes would be to get a dehumidifier from your local hardware store. ...

Comment: Welcome. You pose as many questions as answers here. Please take the [tour] and see if you can refine your advice to better provide just an answer. Ask questions of the asker as comments on the original post if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Get a moisture meter - hygometer - they are $20.  If the RH is above 55% you will get condensation.  Dogs and humans will naturally give off moisture.  Depending on your cooking habits (boiling water with no fan?), showering habits (with no fan?), dish washing habits, laundry (hang dry inside?), number of occupants, plants, etc, you will have a considerable moisture load in the house.

Start with the easiest thing.  Buy a dehumidifier for your room 70 pint or more and keep it on.  Keep in mind that materials will absorb and emit moisture so as you dehumidify the water in materials will come out and it will take a while to dry things out.

If your house is elevated and has a vented crawl space exposed to outside air the next thing depending on climate zone is to vapor barrier and insulate.  You should ask that as a different question with geographic location, pictures of the underside of the house, etc.

Comment: No need for such a huge dehumidifier - mine can just about fill its tank in a day if I've got washing drying, and that's about 3.5l (6-8 pint depending on your pint)

Answer (score 0):

I would lay a ground vapor barrier (heavy plastic sheeting on the ground)
See if that reduces the problem sufficiently. In some cases standing water especially may end up on top of the plastic. In this case a drainage system may be needed and insulating the floor will also help with the moisture and reduce the utility bills.